# Figure out how internet access is being monitored

Tags: monitoring, spyware

I suspect that someone is monitoring my internet connection.

Said person has revealed information about sites I visit and online conversations (Facebook) even when I am not using his/her network.

What software or techniques could I could use to figure out how this person is monitoring me?

Comment: Sounds more like he's got access to your Facebook and/or e-mail accounts than anything. Change your passwords, enable two-factor or two-step authentication where available, and double-check your privacy settings. If you're really worried about the laptop, re-install the OS & software from a trustworthy source.

Comment: Suggest that yhou take a look at a website like http://bit.ly/3wANqZ a blog about this kind of thing. or http://bit.ly/gDxHMw a hackaday article about hardware keyloggers. In the end a lot of people are going to say "his internet his right to know" I call BS. Get that software off there and Consider getting yourself a VPN solution like http://proxpn.com/ to allow you to not be monitored through the internet conenction either. I would also enable two factor authentication whereever possible, in case he knows your passwords, and changing your passwords in case he knows them. Windows included.

Comment: @Iszi "_Privacy rights when you're using someone else's computer or network in general, absent explicit agreements otherwise, should be expected to be non-existent._" It depends in which jurisdiction. In France, even using the employer computer and network, an employee **has** privacy rights.

Comment: @curiousguy Fair enough. Perhaps I should have just left the word "rights" out of that sentence entirely. Regardless of whether the rights actually exist, you should dispose of any expectation of privacy when using someone else's system or infrastructure. By the time you can get around to suing them over the violation, if that's possible in your jurisdiction and feasible for you, irrevocable damage will already have been done.

Comment: When did it become kosher to argue about someone's right to security on sec.se?  None of this is constructive and most of it is beside the point.

Comment: @Indolering One of the reasons my last comment moved beyond arguing about *right* and on to arguing about *expectation*. Again, whether the right exists or not, you must assume that whomever owns a system or infrastructure you're using *can*, and quite possibly *will*, monitor your usage of that system & infrastructure. To do otherwise is to give yourself a false sense of security.

Comment: Deleted the more inflammatory comments. Guys - be nice.

Comment: Freedom of the press belongs to he who owns the press. Get your own internet connection, buy your own equipment, keep your own login information safe and to yourself. Then you can do anything you wish. Works this way whether you're at work or at home. This is the environment under which all adults operate. Only after making this move can your question start to have relevance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you do not state what kind of "help" you want, I will have to guess. So I suggest the following:

*Talk to your father.*

With "talk" as in "talking", not "shouting reproaches". Your father installed this monitoring system for a reason, probably a mixture of making him less worried about your well-being, and a safety feature against the re-enacting of some of the less glamorous parts of your past behaviour.

Engaging into a technical evasion war with your father will not work in the long term. Every good strategist will tell you so: don't fight an enemy who, by definition, will always be more powerful than you. Your father has access to the Ultimate Power: the money flow which pays for every single machine and Internet access that you may use. Even if you could somehow detect and remove whatever monitoring system he put in place in your machine (assuming that's the case), in the long run he will still win, even if that entails removing your computer altogether.

So, admit that this battle is unwinnable, and begin the diplomatic part: negotiate surrendering conditions. You are a kid (or used to be) so you *know* that fathers cannot withstand sweet-talking from their offspring.

Comment: Sorry about not asking what type of help i want. Ive already talked to him about it. And sadly im not a kid, really.

Comment: He denies it when i talk to him about it. I was about to negotiate with him but he doesnt even admit it

Comment: The good old "Give up" approach. No, really, though. If he denies the fact he's doing it, lock him out as much as you can. Read my other comments on your question. I'd post it as an answer if this were unlocked